# Adding two Summations (Leibniz formula)

Tags: calculus

I am wondering how this development is made. I would be really greatful if anyone would like to explain that to me. I don't understand why the right side wont have the form of the product rule like you could see the left side has. This is all from a proof of Leibniz formula by the way.

\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}{p-1 \choose k}{D^{p-k}fD^{k}g + \sum_{l=1}^{p}{p-1 \choose l-1}{D^{p-l}fD^{l}g} =\\{D^{p}fg} +\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}[{p-1 \choose k}+{p-1 \choose k-1}]{D^{p-k}fD^{k}g+f{D^{p}g}}}.
\end{align}

Thank you!

Comment: I think there are missing brackets around the sum of binomial coefficients in the right hand side. Look at the boundaries in the summation.

Comment: Yes that is true! I will add the brackets. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all the step is amounts to separating off the $k=0$ term of the first sum on the left, and the $l=p$ term in the second sum. These are your $D^pfg$ and $fD^pg$ terms, and the rest of both sums now have summation range from 1 to $p-1$. In that range it doesn't matter if we replace index $l$ by index $k$.

Comment: I just noticed that K. Stm. suggested looking at the boundaries of the summation already. That's really all I did here...

Comment: Thank you all for your responses! Much appreciated!